# undefined reference to `ros::console::initializeLogLocation()' in turtlebot_arm_block_manipulation package

Tags: ros, turtlebot, turtlebot-arm

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I added `#include <ros/console.h>` in the header files on top of my .cpp, but I still get this error :

```
undefined reference to `ros::console::initializeLogLocation()'
```

What shall I add in CMakeLists.txt, in catkin_package,
or in package.xml?
I use ROS Hydro.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203252/undefined-reference-to-%60ros::console::initializeloglocation()%27-in-turtlebot_arm_block_manipulation-package/) by [est_CEAR](https://answers.ros.org/users/20539/est_cear/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2015-02-17

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-02-22**:
Please include your current `CMakeLists.txt` and `package.xml`. Remove all the boilerplate comments from it before posting.

(but most likely you are missing a dependency on `roscpp`)

**Comment by [est_CEAR](https://answers.ros.org/users/20539/est_cear/) on 2015-02-22**:
Hi, thanks. As you can read, I included roscpp...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks gvdhoorn

The missing dependencies were in the CMakeLists.txt In the turtlebot_arm_block_manipulation/CMakeLists, two scripts are commented and not compiled to executables, with a "TODO" mention. I uncommented the declaration without adding the target_link_libraries(..) and add_dependencies(...) that are needed.
It was like that :

```
# TODO need review
# add_executable(block_manipulation test/block_manipulation.cpp)
# add_executable(block_manipulation_actions test/block_manipulation_actions.cpp)
```

Should be like that :

```
add_executable(block_manipulation test/block_manipulation.cpp src/cear_move_gripper.cpp)
target_link_libraries(block_manipulation ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(block_manipulation turtlebot_arm_block_manipulation_gencpp)

add_executable(block_manipulation_actions test/block_manipulation_actions.cpp src/cear_move_gripper.cpp)
target_link_libraries(block_manipulation_actions ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(block_manipulation_actions turtlebot_arm_block_manipulation_gencpp)
```

Note that "src/cear_move_gripper.cpp" is a node I implemented to action the gripper.

---

Originally posted by [est_CEAR](https://answers.ros.org/users/20539/est_cear/) with karma: 170 on 2015-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [est_CEAR](https://answers.ros.org/users/20539/est_cear/) on 2015-02-26**:
If somebody can correct it in Github, it would be nice for the next users :)